# .htaccess file not getting loaded

Tags: .htaccess, netbeans, httpd.conf

I am using Netbeans in Linux environment to develop my project. I have put my `.htaccess` in Web pages folder in Netbeans. But my `.htaccess` file is not getting loaded.

1. Now as suggested in many forums I wanted to change `<Directory/>` tag in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file. But There are many such tags. My question is which one I have to edit?
2. I want this file to affect whole directory. So putting it in web pages folder is ok or not?

It might be a repeat question but I could not find a solution in any forum.

Note: I have tried putting garbage or `deny from all` in `.htacces` file it is not getting loaded for sure.

Comment: What Webserver are you using? Are you sure it's the system's Apache and not something else? (maybe something integrated in NetBeans?)

Comment: I am using apache tomcat server installed along with netbeans. Not the system apache httpd server.

Comment: "apache tomcat" is not the same thing as "apache httpd". Tomcat does not support `.htaccess`-files. And changing the httpd-configuration does not affect Tomcat as well.